# Two levels of pointers - one query parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

i have three classes,

```
Class A:
--pointer to class B

Class B:
--Pointer to class C

Class C:
--name
```

i would like to make one query to ClassA, and retrieve ClassC.name how can i do that?

i did try to include classA.ClassB and then getParseObject for classC but this didn't succeed.

Comment: can you explain "name" a little..is this a java class or what..

Comment: did you try intent to pass it..?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `include()` method as follows:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ClassA");

query.include("pointerToB.pointerToC");

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
        for (ParseObject a in results) {
            ParseObject b = a.getParseObject("pointerToB");
            ParseObject c = b.getParseObject("pointerToC");
            String name = c.getString("name");
        }
    }
});
```

This assumes that the column on Class A is called `pointerToB`, and that the column on Class B is called `pointerToC`.

Answer (score 0):

In your class `A` create a getter to return your `B` object:

```
public B getBobject() {
    return myBobject;
}
```

Then do the same in the `B` class to return the `C` object:

```
public C getCobject() {
    return myCobject;
}
```

Finally, do this to get the `name`:

```
myAobject.getBobject().getCobject().name
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `whereMatchesQuery` method with an inner query.
Let's say your class structure is like this:

```
class C {
    int id;
}

class B {
    C c;
}

class A {
    B b;
}
```

then you should user query as:

```
C c = new C();

ParseQuery innerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(B.class);
innerQuery.whereEqualTo("c", c);

ParseQuery<A> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(A.class);
query.whereMatchesQuery("b", innerQuery);

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<A>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<A> objects, ParseException e) {

    }
});
```